# How to migrate to Polymer and PaperElements 1.0 using pubspec.yaml

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I have found Migration guide (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html). My Dart project does not use bower but pubspec.yaml and when I changed dependencies version for PaperElements I get message: `paper_elements has no versions that match >=1.0.0`

```
environment:
 sdk: '>=0.8.10+6 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
 browser: '>=0.10.0+2'
 code_transformers: any
 core_elements: '>=0.6.0'
 dnd: any
 logging: '>=0.9.3'
 paper_elements: '>=1.0.0'
 polymer: any
 polymer_intl: any
 vector_math: any
transformers:
- polymer:
  entry_points:
    web/index.html
  inline_stylesheets:
    packages/polymer/src/build/log_injector.css: false
- $dart2js:
minify: true
```

How to upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_elements

(ignore the deprecated comment in the readme)

**original**

There are no 1.0 elements for Dart yet.
This is work in progress and before they are not published there is no way to use them the way you did previously.
You can use the Polymer.js elements in the meantime of course but then you have to use bower and dart-js-interop.

Comment: OK, I will wait for 1.0 elements for Dart. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: At first Polymer.dart 1.0 is required, then the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/custom_element_apigen package needs to be updated to support Polymer 1.0, then it can be used to generate wrappers for Dart for the elements, but several elements require manual rework. So quite some work to do. You're not the only one waiting ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you know if they have an ETA date for them to complete it?

Comment: The [polymer_elements](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_elements)   package is available as 1.0.0-rc.x version. The deprecation comment in the readme is only for an old version. It's still shown on pub because it shows the readme from the last release version.